# How to learn OpenGL 3.0?

Tags: opengl

Is there a good book that focuses on the programmable aspect of OpenGL 3.0

I want something like the OpenGL Super Bible, but focusing *solely* on the "new testament" part -- the programmable rather than the fixed pipeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Orange Book: http://books.google.it/books?id=kDXOXv_GeswC&dq=opengl+shading+language&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=it&ei=KChiS7-_Ityi_QarxsyMDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false

Answer (score 5):

The latest 5th edition of the OpenGL SuperBible does focus only on the core profile. Unfortunately it includes it's own gltools library so most of the start of the book is really more teaching that toolkit rather than the core profile itself, of course it covers the basic overall layout of a modern opengl program and does seem to fill in the harder stuff later. As you progress though it seems you reimplement the crutch library.

The OpenGL Programming Guide (The Red Book) 7th edition, unfortunately seems to be rather dated. They have marked everything that is in the compatibility profile rather than the core, but thats about it.

There is an [8th edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321773039) being released in December 2012 that is apparently a rewrite teaching modern approaches.

Realistically it would be best to learn the specific areas on the compatibility profile/OpenGL 2.1 then combine them all together into something that is core profile. Doing it all at once is just too much at once.

- First learn Vertex Buffer Objects (and ditch glBegin/glEnd and anything that goes in between).
- Learn manual Matrix operations and stack, or an appropriate library (ditch glPushMatrix/glTranslate/glRotate/glOrthagonal/gluLookAt/glFrustum, you may need to use some compatibility stuff to bind your manually processed marices at this stage but you can ditch them with the shader next step)
- Learn Vertex & Fragment shaders
- Learn how to set the OpenGL context to 3.1+ (Dependant on your windowing system).

Answer (score 2):

The book [OpenGL Programming Guide: The Official Guide to Learning OpenGL, Versions 3.0 and 3.1 (7th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321552628)  was updated and explains the new features of OpenGL 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a shorter, simpler OpenGL book that covers just the programmable pipeline, I'm going out on limb and recommending [OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide](http://opengles-book.com/). OpenGL ES 2 is a subset of OpenGL, to make it simpler for embedded systems.  For most situations where there is more than one way of doing something in OpenGL, the OpenGL ES standard includes only one way.  Version 2 of OpenGL ES is for programmable hardware, and therefore includes just the programmable pipeline stuff. Since OpenGL ES is a subset of OpenGL, everything in OpenGL ES will work on an OpenGL implementation.  Whereas the "OpenGL Programming Guide" is 936 pages long, the "OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide" is merely 480 pages long.

Answer (score 0):

"The Red Book" was **the** openGl book when i was studying it, but that was long ago, you'd have to find out if they've continued to update it as far as v3.

Comment: It's not very well done for v3.

Comment: @anon: Hmm, why, what's the problem with the red book?

Comment: They just marked the legacy stuff as such, but they didn't actually change the focus of the book away from teaching it.

Comment: There releasing an 8th edition being released in a few months that is apparently a rewrite teaching modern OpenGL approaches.